# Python : 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Tags: python, tuples, series, hashable

I have a DataFrame df with text as below :

```
        |---------------------|-----------------------------------|
        |      File_name      |     Content                       | 
        |---------------------|-----------------------------------|
        |          BI1.txt    |  I am writing this letter ...     |
        |---------------------|-----------------------------------|
        |          BI2.txt    |  Yes ! I would like to pursue...  |
        |---------------------|-----------------------------------|
```

I would like to create an additional column which provides the syllable count with :

```
       df['syllable_count']= textstat.syllable_count(df['content'])
```

The error :

```
           Series objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

How can I change the Content column to hashable? How can I fix this error? 
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it this way:

```py
df['syllable_count'] = df.content.apply(lambda x: textstat.syllable_count(x))
```

Comment: And operate on the uniques if you have lots of repeats and then join the results back in.